# TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD for Android using Phonegap

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

With reference to the Android class InputType [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html), and using a system built with phonegap — how can you use `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD` with a given input field? Is this possible?

Comment: Was this useful? An accept would be nice :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use a regular single line text field.
An answer to this question shows some of the possible values: [Getting Search Keyboard on iPhone using PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096328/getting-search-keyboard-on-iphone-using-phonegap)