# Can you display a search keyboard in a PhoneGap app on iOS?

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap app for iOS. I'm using PhoneGap 3.3.0 and jQuery Mobile.

I need to know if you can show the search button on the phone keyboard and listed to that event.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: by looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297099/is-it-possible-to-add-done-button-inside-the-keyboard-in-iphone its looks doable. As for phonegap, im not sure

Comment: I know it can be done using technologies like Titanium, and of course with native XCode, but so far, with PhoneGap, I haven't found any way to do it.

Comment: oh, shhht, sorry, was that for Titanium, i thought it was for Phonegap. Let me see if i can find anything else out here

Comment: Actually this tutorial is for XCode, native app:

http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

I know is possible on Titanium, but in PhoneGap, I haven't found a post refering to it.

Comment: Anyway, I appreciate your help Tasos. If you have any info that you think I might use, I appreciate it.

Comment: If theres no solution you can find. An idea is to create your own keyboard and make it look like the IOS one, example --  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery--net-5774  and then hide the IOS keyboard  ---  https://github.com/iOffice/SoftKeyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<form>
    <input type="search" />
</form>
```

According to this post ([Getting Search Keyboard on iPhone using PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096328/getting-search-keyboard-on-iphone-using-phonegap)) you need to wrap the input with a `form` element to get the desired result.

Comment: I just tested this in my current app on an iPod Touch (5th) gen. Without the the form tags I got the normal keyboard. With the form tags I got the search keyboard.

Comment: I will test right now and let you know Dawson.

Comment: It works with the form tag surrounding the input type search. Now, the thing is, how do I handle the submit event so it doesn't submit the form, instead, I need it to call a JavaScript function. This is a PhoneGap app.

Comment: Already solved it.

<form onsubmit="searchForSpotsForTraq(); return false;">
     <input id="newTraqSpotFilter" name="newTraqSpotFilter" placeholder="Enter a name" type="search" />
    </form>

Now I would like to know if after calling the form submit you can hide the keyboard. Any assistance would be welcome.

Thanks again.

Comment: Try adding to `searchForSpotsForTraq()` `$('#newTraqSpotFilter').blur();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="search" />
```

check it with below link too.
http://mobiforge.com/design-development/html5-mobile-web-forms-and-input-types

Comment: Without the form that, this does not work. Sorry, and thanks.

It seems like you have to surround the tag with a form.